# Slow Get-ADUser query

Tags: powershell, hash, active-directory

Something I do not unterstand. See the following two code examples.

```
  $LDAPResult1 = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(objectCategory=user)(sAMAccountName=*))" -Properties @("distinguishedName","sAMAccountName","extensionAttribute13") -SearchBase "ou=test,dc=test,dc=ch"
  $LDAPElements1=@{}
  $LDAPResult1 |% {$LDAPElements1.Add($_.SAMAccountName, $_.extensionattribute13)}
```

compared with (adding a specific server to ask "-Server 'dc.test.test.ch'"):

```
  $LDAPResult1 = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(objectCategory=user)(sAMAccountName=*))" -Properties @("distinguishedName","sAMAccountName","extensionAttribute13") -SearchBase "ou=test,dc=test,dc=ch" -Server 'dc.test.test.ch'
  $LDAPElements1=@{}
  $LDAPResult1 |% {$LDAPElements1.Add($_.SAMAccountName, $_.extensionattribute13)}
```

The first code takes 30 seconds, the second about 5 minutes. The problem ist not the AD query. This takes around 30 seconds in both cases. But filling the result into the hash table is what is differnet. It seems as if in the second case while filling the hash sill some data is requested from the DC.

What is also interesting. When I wait for five minutes after doing the AD query in case two and then execute the filling into the hash table, then the command takes a second.

I rather would likt to define to what server the command connects in order to execute the folloing commands on the same DC, but this does not make sense if it takes that long.

Can anyone enlighten me …

Addition: We are Talking about 26'000 accounts.

Comment: `Get-ADUser` already gets you user objects only and as far as I know, all user objects have SamAccountNames so there is no need for the ldapfilter. DistinghuishedName and SamAccountName are returned by default, so you don't need to ask for these 2 properties. Try `Get-AdUser -Filter "extensionAttribute13 -like '*'" -Properties extensionAttribute13 | Select-Object SamAccountName, extensionAttribute13`

Comment: You are rigth. However the properties to request are comming from another place. I will test this.

Comment: Ok, adding "-Server $UseDomainController | Select-Object $RunConfig.LDAPRequestAttributes" at the end of the select form LDAP makes it work. Now both code execute in the same time. However I still do not understand why?

Comment: My example results in an array of PsObjects. If you definitively want the result to be a Hashtable, the filling of this takes time. In my experience, using `%` (ForEach-Object) is not the fastest way. This works faster: `foreach ($item in $LDAPResult1) { $LDAPElements1[$item.SamAccountName] = $item.extensionattribute13 }`

Answer (score 2):

I was able to replicate this. The behaviour does change when you specify the `-Server` parameter vs. when you don't.

I used [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to watch network activity and it definitely is talking to the DC when looping through the results returned from using the `-Server` parameter.

I can't explain why, but it seems like the `ADUser` objects returned are not populated with the properties from the search. So when they are accessed, it loads the properties from the DC. I could see this when accessing one particular element in the array:

```
$LDAPResults1[1000]
```

It displayed the properties, but I also saw network activity in Process Monitor. Whereas I do not see network activity when accessing one element from the results returned when not using the `-Server` parameter.

So that kind of explains *what* is happening, but not *why*. And I really don't know why.

However, I have learned that if you want performance when talking to AD, you have to scrap all the "easy" ways and do things yourself. For example, use the .NET [`DirectoryEntry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentry) and [`DirectorySearcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher) classes directly, which can be done in PowerShell using the "type accelerators" `[adsi]` and `[adsisearcher]`. For example, this will do the same and will perform consistently:

```
$dc = "dc.test.test.ch"
$searchBase = "ou=test,dc=test,dc=ch"
$searcher = [adsisearcher]::new([adsi]"LDAP://$dc/$searchBase", "(objectCategory=user)")

$searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName") > $null
$searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("extensionAttribute13") > $null

$searcher.PageSize = 1000

$LDAPElements1=@{}
foreach ($result in $searcher.FindAll()) {
    $LDAPElements1.Add($result.Properties["sAMAccountName"][0], $result.Properties["extensionAttribute13"][0])
}
```

Comment: It does not seem like this. I measured the queries and the LDAP search takes around 30 seconds in BOTH cases. The difference ist filling the hash table. This is what I do not understand.

Comment: @PhilippHungerbühler I see what you mean now that I tested it out. I totally rewrote my answer.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Good to know that you could replicate the situation. I also think the result set, when using the -server switch is not diretly populated. Possibly only the default properties are read in the initial request to the DC and then a subsequent query for the extended property is made when populating the hash table. This would explain why it is so slow then.

Comment: I just ran into this as well using an Azure AD Win10 laptop, which requires providing the Server attribute. Similar to Philipp my initial AD query was quick, yet exporting to CSV or even listing the records was extremely slow. While running I opened the CSV in VSCode and I could actually see it take ~1 second per record being added. I ran the identical code on a domain joined workstation without the Server attribute and it completed in a few seconds.

Comment: I did some additional testing using just get-ADUser xxxx | Select -First 10. When ran on a domain joined PC it runs quickly, Server parameter or not.  When ran from an Azure AD device (which requires the Server parameter) it slowed. Then disabled my network adapter and ran the Select again with a larger range. It ran instantly. I did notice the results returned when connected to the network had five additional fields I've never seen, and these were not present when the network was disabled: WriteDebugStream, WriteErrorStream, WriteInformationStream, WriteVerboseStream, WriteWarningStream

Comment: @MattPenner You can avoid the inconsistency if you use `[adsisearcher]` like I described in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following code to be extremely slow.

```
$user = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter $filter  -Server "xyc" -Properties "sAMAccountName"
```

I was able to rewrite it as:

```
$directorySearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$directorySearcher.SearchRoot = [ADSI]'LDAP://xyz'
[void]$directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add('cn')
[void]$directorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add('sAMAccountName')
$directorySearcher.Filter = "(cn=abcd efg)"
$results = $directorySearcher.FindOne()
Write-Host $results.Properties["samaccountname"] -as [String]
```

and it was a lot faster (by an order of magnitude) than using GetAd-User (but still slow).

Answer (score -1):

Export Get-ADUser results into a temporary CSV file and import it back to some objects.

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter (....) | Export-Csv -Path "TempCSV.csv" -Encoding UTF8 -Delimiter ","
$ADUsers = Import-Csv -Path "TempCSV.csv" -Encoding UTF8 -Delimiter ","
```

Now you can loop the users object.

```
foreach ($ADUser in $ADUsers) { (....) }
```

Comment: This does not appear to answer the OP's question. I'm not quite sure what this answer is attempting to help solve.

Comment: @MattPenner Nobody knows why "Server" parameter makes AD user array loop much slower, so the first answer only gives workaround. So I also just gave another workaroud. When you pipe Get-ADUser query result to csv and pipe it back to AD user array, magically the array loop gets much faster. I don't know why, maybe Export-Csv forces memory cache. Anyway, I know my answer is not a solution but just a workaround.